# Can we access connection string from session variable in SqlDataSource Control?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I have four database on same server, I am using SqlDataSource Control to bind grid view in my application.And I have implemented a drop-down base on its item selection connection string is saved in a session variable. but I don't know how to pass this session variable in connctionstring property of SqlDataSource Control

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsMyAlarm" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AlarmDirectorDTUConnectionString %>"  SelectCommand="AD_FetchAlarmSubscriptionsByUserID" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
     <SelectParameters>
                <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="ContactId" SessionField="CurrentUser" Type="Int32" />
      </SelectParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

*In This property I want to pass a session variable*

```
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AlarmDirectorDTUConnectionString %>"
```

Is it possible? or can i achive this by other way please suggest me I am open for suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the session variable in code behind page_load.

```
dsMyAlarm.connectionString=Session["constr"];
```

or refer to the document data binding expression.https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/976112